# Macro on Access to hide fields does not work

Tags: ms-access, visibility

I am trying to figure out how to make a Macro work in Access but have never used it before. The program is telling me there is a type mismatch. I cannot figure out what is wrong with the way it is written, but there is certainly an issue because it does not do what I wish. What I am trying to do is make a field visible when a checkbox is checked and invisible when it is not.

My Macro page looks like this:
If [Forms]![Form name]![Checkbox]=True Then

Set Property

Control Name: Control

Property: Visible

Value:True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in the VBA editor (in "your form name" code):

```
Private Sub Checkbox1_Click()

If Me.Checkbox1 = True Then
    Me.Control1.Visible = True
Else
    Me.Control1.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

Remember to change "Checkbox1" and "Control1" to the appropriate controls names.

Comment: Miguel, I appreciate the reply. I put in the number -1 but it seems to switch it to "True" when I exit out of the Macro builder and reenter. Tried again to be sure but no luck.

Comment: What about: "[Forms]![Form name]![Checkbox]=-1"

Comment: I think it is working, so I will use this to make boxes invisible. How come it worked on VBA code but not on the Macro Builder?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the macro builder but with the correct syntax it should also work. VBA is far more flexible anyway.

Comment: Well I can't make it work in macro so will go with this. Thanks